# Mouseover and Mouseout listener for Google Maps marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I would like to have bouncing effect, when I mouseover on marker, and stop animation when mouseleave.

I'm trying to use mouseover and mouseout event on listeners like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
  this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
  this.setAnimation(null);
});
```

But this is looking weird.
I can't explain the wrong behaviour in words - please see this 15 seconds video which I recorded:

===> http://youtu.be/Hcy8823nNQU

What I need is probably mouseleave instead of mouseout, but that event is not provided by their API.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key is to set animation only when it is not set already, as:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    if (this.getAnimation() == null || typeof this.getAnimation() === 'undefined') {

        /* 
        Because of the google maps bug of moving cursor several times over and out of marker
        causes bounce animation to break - we use small timer before triggering the bounce animation
        */

        clearTimeout(bounceTimer);

        var that = this;

        bounceTimer = setTimeout(function(){
             that.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        },
        500);

    }
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {

     if (this.getAnimation() != null) {
        this.setAnimation(null);
     }

     // If we already left marker, no need to bounce when timer is ready
     clearTimeout(bounceTimer);

});
```

I created a **[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNQRB/10/)** for you.

**Edited:**

It seems that using marker as `draggable: false` will break the functionality, so If you want animation to still work you need to add also `optimized: false` , updated my fiddle to contain these. Also I saw that there is a bug if marker animation is toggled in and out too fast, added small timer to indicate before we start bounce animation, seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. For me it's not working, definitely I have some problem somewhere in other code. For instance when I remove conditions from your JS fiddle, it's still working.

Comment: Oooh, I got it. I need to add "draggable: true", and then it's working! Look, here's your fiddle, but I set draggable to false and we see the problem I have - http://jsfiddle.net/Mas4D/1/ But why? I don't want marker to be draggable, hmm.

Comment: I answer in a sec, I seemed to find maybe some bugs of google maps and how to overcome them. :)